# Perl subtract two dates

Tags: perl, datetime

I am fairly new in Perl. 
I am trying to subtract two dates in this format

```
15.07.16 23:13:34
15.07.16 20:04:24
```

I know that I have to convert this string in a date object. My problem is I am restricted to the basic perl without installing extra packages. Is there a way to do it?

My Version is v5.8.4 and the output should be `03:09:10`.

Comment: Which version of Perl do you have? What are you expecting as the output? You can [edit] your question.

Comment: The linked duplicate is basically what you want. Just the pattern for `strptime` is a bit different. See http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strptime.3.html to learn how to construct the right pattern.

Comment: My Version is v5.8.4 and the output should be 03:09:10

Comment: Then you might not have Time::Piece. Please do `perl -MTime::Piece\ 999` in your command line. `corelist Time::Piece` says it's been released with 5.9.5 for me.

Comment: Can't locate Time/Piece.pm

Comment: Then we don't have a duplicate, and you need to use a different tool.

Comment: If you don't have Time::Piece installed then one of two things is true. Either you're using a really old version of Perl (Time::Piece has been standard since 5.10.0 was released in 2007) or you're running one of Red Hat's [crippled Perl installations](http://perlhacks.com/2012/08/a-cautionary-tale/) and you need to get the `perl-core` RPM installed. Either of these circumstances will severely affect your ability to write good Perl code and should be fixed before you try to do too much more work.

Comment: @Dave they said they have 5.8.4 [in a comment above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40279955/perl-subtract-two-dates?noredirect=1#comment67819114_40279955)

Comment: Yeah. I see that. I guess that's the biggest problem that they need to get fixed :-)

Comment: @Dave how did you even get stuff done in that time? Makes you appreciate all the effort that people put into CPAN... :)

Comment: What would be your expected output if the order of the 2 strings was reversed?

Answer (score 4):

You say that you're using Perl 5.8.4. You really need to get that updated and get the ability to install CPAN modules.

But, here's a way to do what you want using only core Perl functionality that was available in 5.8.4.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::Local;

my $date1 = '15.07.16 23:13:34';
my $date2 = '15.07.16 20:04:24';

my $diff = date2sec($date1) - date2sec($date2);

print secs2duration($diff);

sub date2sec {
  my ($date) = @_;

  my ($day, $mon, $yr, $hr, $min, $sec) = split(/[. :]/, $date);

  # I've assumed that your timestamps are in your local timezone,
  # so I've used timelocal() here. If your timestamps are actually
  # UTC, you should use timegm() instead.
  return timelocal($sec, $min, $hr, $day, $mon-1, 2000 + $yr);
}

sub secs2duration {
  my ($secs) = @_;

  my $hours = int($secs / (60*60));
  $secs %= (60*60);
  my $mins = int($secs / 60);
  $secs %= 60;

  return sprintf '%02d:%02d:%02d', $hours, $mins, $secs;
}
```

Comment: without hearing anything to the contrary, I would assume these are *not* in local time (so timegm instead of timelocal)

Comment: @ysth: In my experience, people who don't mention time zones are more likely to be dealing with local time - which is why I chose `timelocal()`. But I'll add a comment to clarify that.

Comment: Surely timezone is irrelevant here because we're looking for a delta?  The important thing is that both inputs are in _the same_ timezone - and we have no choice but to assume that :-)

Comment: @ardavey: What if the times were local times and they were on either side of a DST-changeover?

Comment: @DaveCross Ah, there's the edge case ... and that's just after I've been chasing BST/GMT bugs :-D